# Was a photo of a burned Israeli baby's corpse generated by AI?

Tags: israel, photography, israel-hamas-war, ai

Shortly after the [7 October 2023 Hamas-led attack on Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Hamas-led_attack_on_Israel), the Prime Minister of Israel, Benjamin Netanyahu, released some photos, including that purporting to be a baby's charred corpse.

**WARNING: The links below contain graphic images that may be distressing.**

*Defense Politics Asia* [claimed](https://defensepoliticsasia.com/israel-published-ai-generated-photo-of-burnt-charred-baby-as-hamas-victim/) a few days later ([also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pGOyL7jCQA) on their YouTube channel) that one of the photos showing a burned baby was doctored ("AI generated") by the Israeli government.

They show a photo of a puppy in exactly the same setting, and claim it was the original.

Their analysis seems to rely mainly on the [*AI Or Not*](https://www.aiornot.com/) tool scoring the burned babies photo as "AI generated", while the puppy photo has "human generated".

The claim has been repeated, with less detail, in other venues.

Is this analysis correct/conclusive?

Comment: It seems not  https://www.404media.co/ai-images-detectors-are-being-used-to-discredit-the-real-horrors-of-war/

Comment: Don't the two claims contradict each other. Either, the picture was AI generated, or, it was a doctored puppy picture. It can't be both. Also, if the other two pictures not put into question, why was it needed to fake another picture? What is the source of the puppy picture?

Comment: @SIMEL: the source from my later comment also discusses "partially AI generated" images too, so I guess that's a thing. But says that's not really the case here. You're right about the logical pointlessness of [allegedly] faking *one* image, when there's two of them of the same scene... the other one passing even the Optic tool. In the video, the DPA guy wonders about that himself, but still sticks to his conclusion that one of the images is fake...

Comment: still doesn't make sense, the Israeli gov. is capable enough to do good photoshop work, if they wanted to manipulate an existing picture, why use an unpredictable and inaccurate ai tool rather than use a professional? This is a pretty obvious case of Occam's razor, the ai detection tool is wrong. Also, in the replies to Hinkle's tweet, people showed that they got different results for the same picture in the same tool.

Comment: Also, beyond the fact that we didn't get an origin for the puppy picture, the baby picture has something censored on the body bag. Which would make sense in a case of real body as it might have identifying details of the baby. It doesn't really make sense to censor it on the puppy image, but it's still censored. Where is the original uncensored image?

Comment: @SIMEL: it seemed a bit obvious to me given where that was posted (4chan) and by accompanying text that it was most likely trolling, but the DPA guy took it seriously.

Comment: Found an additional source for answering this https://www.bellingcat.com/resources/2023/09/11/testing-ai-or-not-how-well-does-an-ai-image-detector-do-its-job/

Comment: "We find bodies that are burned or in a state of decomposition, we can easily be mistaken and think the body is a child's," said Haim Otmazgin, a Zaka leader on an interview with France24. So the absence of babies burned during the 7th october attack is not proof that the photo was edited.